# Diagonal labels orientation on x-axis in heatmap(s)

Tags: r, label, data-visualization, heatmap, lattice

Creating heatmaps in R has been a topic of many posts, discussions and iterations. My main problem is that it's tricky to combine visual flexibility of solutions available in lattice `levelplot()` or basic graphics `image()`, with effortless clustering of basic's `heatmap()`, pheatmap's `pheatmap()` or gplots' `heatmap.2()`. It's a tiny detail I want to change - diagonal orientation of labels on x-axis. Let me show you my point in the code.

```
#example data
d <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5)
colnames(d) = paste("bip", 1:5, sep = "")
rownames(d) = paste("blob", 1:5, sep = "")
```

You can change orientation to diagonal easily with `levelplot()`:

```
require(lattice)
levelplot(d, scale=list(x=list(rot=45)))
```

[image]

but applying the clustering seems pain. So does other visual options like adding borders around heatmap cells.

Now, shifting to actual `heatmap()` related functions, clustering and all basic visuals are super-simple - almost no adjustment required:

```
heatmap(d)
```

[image]

and so is here:

```
require(gplots)
heatmap.2(d, key=F)
```

[image]

and finally, my favourite one:

```
require(pheatmap)
pheatmap(d)
```

[image]

But all of those have **no option to rotate the labels**. Manual for `pheatmap` suggests that I can use `grid.text` to custom-orient my labels. What a joy it is - especially when clustering and changing the ordering of displayed labels. Unless I'm missing something here...

Finally, there is an old good `image()`. I can rotate labels, in general it' most customizable solution, but no clustering option.

```
image(1:nrow(d),1:ncol(d), d, axes=F, ylab="", xlab="")
text(1:ncol(d), 0, srt = 45, labels = rownames(d), xpd = TRUE)
axis(1, label=F)
axis(2, 1:nrow(d), colnames(d), las=1)
```

[image]

So what should I do to get my ideal, quick heatmap, with clustering and orientation and nice visual features hacking? My best bid is changing `heatmap()` or `pheatmap()` somehow because those two seem to be most versatile in adjustment. But any solutions welcome.

Comment: Base graphics doesn't allow your to control the rotation of tick labels to arbitrary angles --- hence you have to use the `text` "hack" that you show in the last `image` example. I would probably pass `xaxt = FALSE` to my `heatmap` call and then add the axis without labels and then add the labels using `text`, just as you do with `image`.

Comment: @GavinSimpson The problem with this approach is that you have to manually define the order of labels on x-axis when you're clustering. Possible, but a bit painful. Still, thanks for pointing out to me that `heatmap()` is build using base graphics rather then grid (I thought it was grid like `pheatmap()`).

Comment: There is a solution to that - I have something working that I'm just writing up as an answer. It was a little more involved than I thought. Solution coming soon...

Comment: +1 for an entertaining read as well as being a good question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To fix `pheatmap`, all you really want to do is to go into `pheatmap:::draw_colnames` and tweak a couple of settings in its call to `grid.text()`. Here's one way to do that, using `assignInNamespace()`. (It may need additional adjustments, but you get the picture ;):

```
library(grid)     ## Need to attach (and not just load) grid package
library(pheatmap)

## Your data
d <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5)
colnames(d) = paste("bip", 1:5, sep = "")
rownames(d) = paste("blob", 1:5, sep = "")

## Edit body of pheatmap:::draw_colnames, customizing it to your liking
draw_colnames_45 <- function (coln, ...) {
    m = length(coln)
    x = (1:m)/m - 1/2/m
    grid.text(coln, x = x, y = unit(0.96, "npc"), vjust = .5, 
        hjust = 1, rot = 45, gp = gpar(...)) ## Was 'hjust=0' and 'rot=270'
}

## For pheatmap_1.0.8 and later:
draw_colnames_45 <- function (coln, gaps, ...) {
    coord = pheatmap:::find_coordinates(length(coln), gaps)
    x = coord$coord - 0.5 * coord$size
    res = textGrob(coln, x = x, y = unit(1, "npc") - unit(3,"bigpts"), vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1, rot = 45, gp = gpar(...))
    return(res)}

## 'Overwrite' default draw_colnames with your own version 
assignInNamespace(x="draw_colnames", value="draw_colnames_45",
ns=asNamespace("pheatmap"))

## Try it out
pheatmap(d)
```

[image]

Comment: Well, for you it's a small tweak, for me it's a big step. At the end of the day, you are the Master Of The Grid ;) Thanks Josh!

Comment: @GeekOnAcid -- Well, thanks as usual for the interesting question! In truth, this is the first time I've used `assignInNamespace()`, and both it and `pheatmap` are nice finds. I first did `trace(pheatmap:::draw_colnames, edit=TRUE)` to try a couple of things out, but once I found a fix, wanted something less interactive than that. Turns out `assignInNamespace()` is the ticket, and I'll be using it quite a bit going forward. Cheers.

Comment: +1 The same thing could be done for the `heatmap` version too of course, but it is easier in that case to just run the plot call twice and use `add.expr`.

Comment: Any idea how to increase margin if the labels are long and go off left side?

Comment: This workaround is no longer necessary. The `angle_col` argument is supported in version 1.0.12 of pheatmap (see answer below for details).

Answer (score 15):

The latest version of [`pheatmap`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pheatmap/index.html) (1.0.12) [released on 2019-01-04](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pheatmap/NEWS) supports this with the `angle_col` argument.

```
#example data
d <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5)
colnames(d) = paste("bip", 1:5, sep = "")
rownames(d) = paste("blob", 1:5, sep = "")

#update to latest version on CRAN
install.packages("pheatmap")
library("pheatmap")
pheatmap(d, angle_col = 45)
```

[image: pretty heatmap with angled column labels]

I've created a package on GitHub with an improved version of the `heatmap.2` function. This supports adjusting the axis labels, including the `srtCol` argument which is passed to the `axis` function. It can be installed from: https://github.com/TomKellyGenetics/heatmap.2x

```
library("devtools")
install_github("TomKellyGenetics/heatmap.2x")
library("heatmap.2x")

heatmap.2x(d, scale = "none", trace = "none", col = heat.colors, srtCol = 45)
```

[image: enhanced heatmap.2x with angled column labels]

As of [version 2.12.1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gplots/NEWS) of [`gplots`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gplots), the `heatmap.2` function also supports the `srtCol` argument.

```
library("gplots")
heatmap.2(d, scale = "none", trace = "none", srtCol = 45)
```

[image: heatmap.2 with angled column labels]

Answer (score 12):

It is a little more complex than my comment presumed, because `heatmap` breaks up the plotting region in order to draw the dendrograms and the last plot region is not the `image` plot to which you want to attach the labels.

There is a solution though as `heatmap` provides the `add.expr` argument which takes an expression to be evaluated when the `image` is drawn. One also needs to know the reordering of the labels that takes place due to the dendrogram ordering. The last bit involves a bit of an inelegant hack as I will draw the heatmap first to get the reordering information and then use that to draw the heatmap properly with the angled labels.

First an example from `?heatmap`

```
 x  <- as.matrix(mtcars)
 rc <- rainbow(nrow(x), start = 0, end = .3)
 cc <- rainbow(ncol(x), start = 0, end = .3)
 hv <- heatmap(x, col = cm.colors(256), scale = "column",
               RowSideColors = rc, ColSideColors = cc, margins = c(5,10),
               xlab = "specification variables", ylab =  "Car Models",
               main = "heatmap(<Mtcars data>, ..., scale = \"column\")")
```

At this stage, the labels aren't how we want them, but `hv` contains the information we need to reorder the `colnames` of `mtcars` in its component `$colInd`:

```
> hv$colInd
 [1]  2  9  8 11  6  5 10  7  1  4  3
```

You use this like you would the output from `order` e.g.:

```
> colnames(mtcars)[hv$colInd]
 [1] "cyl"  "am"   "vs"   "carb" "wt"   "drat" "gear" "qsec" "mpg"  "hp"  
[11] "disp"
```

Now use that to generate the labels we want in the correct order:

```
 labs <- colnames(mtcars)[hv$colInd]
```

Then we re-call `heatmap` but this time we specify `labCol = ""` to suppress the labelling of the column variables (using zero length strings). We also use a call to `text` to draw the labels at the desired angle. The call to `text` is:

```
text(x = seq_along(labs), y = -0.2, srt = 45, labels = labs, xpd = TRUE)
```

which is essentially what you have in your question. Play with the value of `y` as you need to adjust this to the length of the strings so as to have the labels not overlap with the `image` plot. We specify `labels = labs` to pass in the labels we want draw in the order required. The entire `text` call is passed to `add.expr` unquoted. Here is the entire call:

```
 hv <- heatmap(x, col = cm.colors(256), scale = "column",
               RowSideColors = rc, ColSideColors = cc, margins = c(5,10),
               xlab = "specification variables", ylab =  "Car Models",
               labCol = "",
               main = "heatmap(<Mtcars data>, ..., scale = \"column\")",
               add.expr = text(x = seq_along(labs), y = -0.2, srt = 45,
                               labels = labs, xpd = TRUE))
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Nice one. Thanks. Getting the labels position is crucial, so thanks for this solution, however 'crude' it is:)

Comment: Yeah, very nice. It was just last month I learned from you about `plot(..., panel.last)`, and now here is `heatmap(..., add.expr)`. Good reminders that I should keep a better eye out for handy arguments like those (or, maybe better, go scan some of your back posts for similar gems).

Answer (score 8):

I am also looking for method to rotate label text with heatmap. Eventually I have managed to find this solution:

```
library(gplots)

library(RColorBrewer)

heatmap.2(x,col=rev(brewer.pal(11,"Spectral")),cexRow=1,cexCol=1,margins=c(12,8),trace="none",srtCol=45)
```

The key argument is `srtCol(or srtRow for row labels)`, which is used to rotate column labels in gplots.

Comment: Nope, when I use my example data with your solution it doesn't work. It gives me an error that `"srtCol" is not a graphical parameter`.

Answer (score 5):

A solution using `lattice::levelplot` and `latticeExtra::dendrogramGrob`:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
```

The example data:

```
d <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5)
colnames(d) = paste("bip", 1:5, sep = "")
rownames(d) = paste("blob", 1:5, sep = "")
```

You must define the dendrograms for rows and columns (computed
internally in `heatmap`):

```
dd.row <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(d)))
row.ord <- order.dendrogram(dd.row)

dd.col <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(d))))
col.ord <- order.dendrogram(dd.col)
```

and pass them to the `dendrogramGrob` function in the `legend`
argument of `levelplot`.

I have defined a new theme with colors from `RColorBrewer`, and
modified the width and color of the cells borders with `border`
and `border.lwd`:

```
myTheme <- custom.theme(region=brewer.pal(n=11, 'RdBu'))

levelplot(d[row.ord, col.ord],
          aspect = "fill", xlab='', ylab='',
          scales = list(x = list(rot = 45)),
          colorkey = list(space = "bottom"),
          par.settings=myTheme,
          border='black', border.lwd=.6,
          legend =
          list(right =
               list(fun = dendrogramGrob,
                    args =
                    list(x = dd.col, ord = col.ord,
                         side = "right",
                         size = 10)),
               top =
               list(fun = dendrogramGrob,
                    args =
                    list(x = dd.row,
                         side = "top"))))
```

[image: levelplot with dendrogram]

You can even use the `shrink` argument to scale the cells size
proportional to their value.

```
levelplot(d[row.ord, col.ord],
          aspect = "fill", xlab='', ylab='',
          scales = list(x = list(rot = 45)),
          colorkey = list(space = "bottom"),
          par.settings=myTheme,
          border='black', border.lwd=.6,
          shrink=c(.75, .95),
          legend =
          list(right =
               list(fun = dendrogramGrob,
                    args =
                    list(x = dd.col, ord = col.ord,
                         side = "right",
                         size = 10)),
               top =
               list(fun = dendrogramGrob,
                    args =
                    list(x = dd.row,
                         side = "top"))))
```

[image: levelplot with dendrogram and scaled cell sizes]

Answer (score 4):

I was able to take Gavin Simpson's answer and trimmed it down a bit to work for me for simple prototyping purposes, where `data1` is the read.csv() object, and `data1_matrix` of course the matrix produced from that

```
heatmap(data_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col=heat.colors(64), scale='column', margins=c(5,10),
   labCol="", add.expr = text(x = seq_along(colnames(data1)), y=-0.2, srt=45, 
   labels=colnames(data1), xpd=TRUE))
```

Boom! Thanks Gavin.

A key bit for this to work is the part before the `add.expr` bit where he set the labCol to "", which is necessary to prevent the former (straight-down) labels from overlapping with the new 45 degree ones