# control font on x-axis labels using heatmap() in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I have data where the long labels need to be preserved in my plot, but they are getting cut off by the defaults and I'm struggling to control them. As an example:

```
x <- c(13,12,7,5,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
y <- c(0,0,0,0,0,12,9,9,7,5,4,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
z <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,3,1)

m <- matrix(c(x, y, z), ncol = 3)

colnames(m) <- c("Brassica oleracea var italia", "Brassica oleracea var capitata", "Cynara cardunculus var scolymus")

heatmap(m, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, scale = "none")
```

I tried

```
heatmap(m, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, scale = "none", cexCol = 0.5)
```

will make them smaller, but can anyone advise on how to angle them? Is this even possible with native R graphs?

Comment: See [_boulder_ruby_'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15858086/6574038) at the canoniocal. You still might consider to abbreviate the labels and explain it in the caption, which is more usual in scientific literature.